# Overloaded method value [apply] cannot be applied to (play.api.data.Mapping[String])

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am studying to use play and scala to build a web app, and have some problem with checkbox post.

My controller:

```
  val serviceForm = Form(tuple(
    "id" -> number,
    "name" -> text,
    "checkboxList" -> list(text)
  )
 )
```

And my html

```
<form action="/testCheckbox" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="id">
 <input type="text" name="name">
 <input type="checkbox" name="checboxList[]"> cb1
 <input type="checkbox" name="checboxList[]"> cb2
 <input type="checkbox" name="checboxList[]"> cb3
..
</form>
```

POST DATA(from chrome debug tools):

```
id: 1
name: test
checkboxList[]: 1
checkboxList[]: 2
checkboxList[]: 2
```

Then play says [web]:

```
Overloaded method value [apply] cannot be applied to (play.api.data.Mapping[String])
```

console:

```
overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
[error]   (rh:     play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Array[Byte],play.api.mvc.SimpleResult] <and>
[error]   (request: play.api.mvc.Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent])scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult]
[error]  cannot be applied to (play.api.data.Mapping[String])
[error]       "checkboxList" -> list(text)
[error]                       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Please post the code for your controller action where you're actually binding the form.

Comment: Your `Form` compiles fine for me. Some more context from where you're using the form will be needed.

Comment: It works after I changed `list` to `seq`, what is the difference between `list` and `seq`?